# chart.js vue.js вывод данных

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuex

Всем привет,у меня есть график

```
export default {
  extends: Line,
  data() {
    return {
      datacollection: {
        labels: ['Opel', 'Mazda', 'Nissan', 'Lada', 'Lexus', 'Kia', 'Toyota', 'Chevrolet', 'Fiat'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Data One',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
          borderWidth: 1,
          pointBorderColor: '#249EBF',
          data: [40, 20, 30, 50, 90, 10, 20, 40, 50, 70, 90, 100]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            },
            gridLines: {
              display: true
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            }
          }]
        },
        legend: {
          display: true
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.datacollection, this.options)
  }
}
```

Мне нужно вывести данные ,которые я получаю из API 
они в таком виде

```
[ {
  "id" : "1000",
  "creditAgreementNumber" : "1173166",
  "creditAgreementStatus" : "Legal Collection",
  "creditAgreementSubStatus" : "Умерший с просрочкой",
  "totalDebt" : 243641.00,
  "userId" : "1000",
  "userFullName" : "admin admin admin",
  "car" : {
    "id" : "1000",
    "pledgeAgreementNumber" : "1173166/7",
    "make" : "Opel",
    "model" : "Astra",
    "manufactureYear" : 2000,
    "color" : "черный",
    "vin" : "JHLRE48577C415490",
    "licensePlate" : "X001XX73",
    "enginePower" : 90.00,
    "parkingId" : "67",
    "archival" : true,
    "hasImportWarnings" : false,
    "evaluationStatus" : "EVALUATION_FINISHED"
  }]
```

И повторяются,мне надо в labels вывести поля make,а в data вывести totalDebt
Получаю данные я через store вот так

```
   import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  state:{
    contracts:[]
  },
  actions: {
    setContracts ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('api/v1/contracts', {
      }).then(response => {
        commit('setContracts', response.data)
      });
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setContracts (state, payload) {
      state.contracts = payload
    }
  },
  getters: {
    filteredContracts: (state) => (search) => {
      let result = state.contracts

      if (search) {
        result = result.filter((item) => {
          if (item.car.make.indexOf(search) !== -1
            || item.car.model.indexOf(search) !== -1
            || item.car.licensePlate.indexOf(search) !== -1
            || item.car.vin.indexOf(search) !== -1
            || item.client.clientName.indexOf(search) !== -1) {
            return item;
          }
        });
      }

      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Подскажите как такое сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В vuex добавить в getters:

```
getCars (state) {
  var ar = []
  state.contracts.forEach(el => {
    ar.push(el.car.make)
  })
  return ar
},
getData (state) {
  var ar = []
  state.contracts.forEach(el => {
    ar.push(el.totalDebt)
  })
  return ar
}
```

В компоненте

```
  mounted () {
    this.datacollection.labels = this.$store.getters.getCars
    this.datacollection.datasets[0].data = this.$store.getters.getData
    this.renderChart(this.datacollection, this.options)
  }
```

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос,геттер у меня вон как выглядит,и все равно немного не понял как их в график передать,можете пожалуйста подробнее показать на моем примере?

Comment: Добавил проверьте. Если данные не меняются в сторе постоянно , должно хватать.

Comment: по сути можно обойтись и записью `this.datacollection.labels = this.$store.getters.filteredContracts` без компьтеда

Comment: вообще диаграмму не выводит пишет TypeError: me.ticks.map is not a function

Comment: Сейчас кину себе в проект.

Comment: Ну конечно у вас же filteredContracts это функция поэтому нужно добавить (). Тут другой вопрос совсем. Вам одних имен мало. `this.$store.getters.filteredContracts()` Если получать так, то кроме имен больше ничего не будет.

Comment: Он выводит [object object]

Comment: мне надо чтобы он в labels выводил make (т.е opel,kia,mazda и т.д),а в data выводил totalDebt,и т.к массив большой,чтобы выводил все,которые встреаются

Comment: Ну правильно, он возвращает объект и его нужно обработать, какие данные вы выводите вторые? Какие показатели?

Comment: Вам нужны только эти данные?

Comment: да ,только эти ,make и totalDebt,чтобы они были на разных осях

Comment: Читайте выше я кинул ответ, если хотите чтобы обрабатывал vuex

Comment: Огромное спасибо,все получилось

Comment: Пожалуйста. Но вы должны учи то, что это будут все машины. Если нужны только те, которые фильтруются вашим filteredContracts то нужно переносить обработчик в компонент! И там привязываться компьютедами.